# help with circuit design / device selection

Tags: differential, vcm

I am trying to design a circuit that has:

- Vcc == 5v  (microcontroller -- arduino, etc)
- variable input (either from PWM or DAC)
- has a digital feedback signal to the microcontroller
- output is a differential line driver that can be either positive or negative

The differential output would be +/- 0 to 1 or 2 volts, variable, based on the input.
Output current is < 500mA max.
in other words, the output is proportional to the input, and may be negative

The input would be controlled by the microcontroller, after adjusting from the feedback

similar to this, but with a single +5v supply, single input and mosfet outputs...
https://i.stack.imgur.com/vh7Wg.png

any pointers to such a device is appreciated....
or how to search for one would work also

Comment: look at motor driver circuits

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Comment: I am trying to find a "fully differential motor driver"

I have found a lot of fully differential devices, but all of them seem to be very low current for adc inputs. I need to drive a voice coil motor, so the ideal device would have higher current outputs.

Has anyone designed such a circuit ? Or can direct me to a device ?